# Want Icloud for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

**Hi** I want icloud for Ubuntu 20.04 and I know that its available in the Ubuntu app store but its developer is different not Apple. So is it a original build and safe to use? I know that its a stupid question . Thankyou.

Comment: "safe to use" could have many possible metrics. Which one were you thinking of?

Comment: In Microsoft store developer of icloud is apple.inc and in Ubuntu app store its launched by another person. So my doubt is that like , is the app in Ubuntu app store **official or inofficial build** ? @user535733

Comment: "Official" vs."Unofficial" seems a misleading metric. Canonical engineers independently built ALL of Ubuntu 20.04 from source instead of precompiled binaries from upstream -- it's all "unofficial" (but properly licensed). Historically, upstream projects and developers rarely create their own packages for Linux, so it falls to *volunteers* like you and me to build and package the software. Feel free to complain to Apple about their lack of official Linux builds -- you paid them a lot of money for your Apple products, you are their *customer*.